# Show that $\mathbb Q$ is not a $G_{\delta}$-set.

Tags: proof-verification, metric-spaces

**The question is** $ : $

Show that $\mathbb Q$ is not a $G_{\delta}$-set.

**My attempt** $ : $

Since $\mathbb R$ endowed with the usual metric is complete so by Baire's category theorem $\mathbb R$ is a set of second category.

If possible let $\mathbb Q$ is a $G_{\delta}$ set.Then there exist a countable collection of open sets $\{A_{n}\}$ such that

$$\mathbb Q = \cap_{n=1}^{\infty} A_{n} .$$

Since $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R$ so each $A_{n}$ is dense in $\mathbb R$.Each $A_{n}$ being open the set $\mathbb R \setminus A_{n}$ is closed and nowhere dense in $\mathbb R$ for each $n$.

Now

$$\mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q = \cup_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb R \setminus A_{n} .$$

This shows that $\mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q$ is a set of first category. Again since $\mathbb Q$ is a set of first category so is $\mathbb R$ , being the union of $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q$ both of which are sets of first category which contradicts the fact that $\mathbb R$ is the set of second category.Hence $\mathbb Q$ is not a $G_{\delta}$ set.

Comment: Your general reasoning is correct. It could stand to be a little clearer: in particular, why exactly $\mathbb{R} \setminus A_n$ is closed and nowhere dense, and why a finite union of first category sets is first category.

Comment: @Ian not only finite union but also the countable union of the set of first category is a set of first category being countable union of countable nowhere dense sets and countable union of countable sets is countable.

Comment: Yes, but you don't need the countable case here. :)